# how to dislplay once my fragment when app install in android

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am new to  this concept ,How to display my fragment after in application,that fragment only display at after installing my app,  please any one suggest me how to do that

Comment: why not you use a sharedpreference

Answer (score 1):

Basically you need to store a value outside of the application itself. Shared Preferences or a database (eg SQLite) or a file could be used. The former, Shared Preferences, would be the simplest. There are loads of tutorials and examples eg [Android Shared preferences example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example)

You could use a boolean type or even simply check for the existence of any type and then set or create it respectively.